# Irreducibility over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to prove that $x^5+5x^2+4$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$.
I can see that is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ using reduction $\pmod5$, but how can I conclude?

Comment: What is $\zeta_5$

Comment: a primitive fifth root of unity

Comment: Is the assertion being made that $x^5+5x^2+4$ is irreducible mod $5$? If so I do not understand it, since there is a root modulo $5$.